# Code indentation rendered incorrectly in suggested edit view

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, diff

I just reviewed this [crap suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8260279) with a deceptive diff. Looking at the rendered output on the left hand side, it looks like there were a couple of stray spaces - in front of the lines `opt[0].value = 'a';` and `var select1 = document.createElement("select");` - which the edit removed:

#### Rendered Output View:

[image]

But looking at the markdown view, and the question itself, we can see that these stray spaces don't really exist:

#### Markdown view:

[image]

#### Actual question page:

[image]

It seems likely that this deceptive rendered output diff is what led three reviewers to accept the edit despite it being, in fact, pointless and destructive.

Comment: (After staring at the diff view for too long) Are you sure it is "pointless and destructive"? Do you infer that from the amount of deleted and inserted code? To me it really looks like the diff view is only over-emphasizing the inserted blank lines by considering everything after "deleted+new text".

Comment: @Jongware I'm sure, and the amount of deleted and inserted code has nothing to do with it. The edit wrongly indents all but the first line by four spaces, and adds an erroneous space at the beginning of the first line. "Destructive" might be too strong a word since the edit only changes whitespace, but the change is definitely bad.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that when creating the diffs we grouped subsequent newline characters together, so instead of "insert one newline", the diff engine output "remove one newline, then insert two newlines". And "remove something invisible" is shown as removing a space in the diff so you see that *something* was removed here.

From the next build on the newlines won't be grouped together anymore, so it will look like this instead:

[image: screenshot of the diff after the change]